# How to use compiler directives in Playground Page File?

Tags: swift, xcode

Some codes like this

```
#if teacherMode
    let clientCode = ClientCode(factoryType: TeacherAuthViewFactory.self)
#else
    let clientCode = ClientCode(factoryType: StudentAuthViewFactory.self)
#endif
```

I copy the code above on the playground page, then run the code.

I see the result of the student every time.

How to set the `teacherMode` to change the result?

Comment: If it had been an Xcode project you would have defined teacherMode as a compiler flag in the targets build settings using `-D teacherMode` but I have no idea how to do that in a playground nor do I understand why you would need it in a playground

Comment: Are you talking about playgrounds created with Xcode, or playgrounds created with the Swift Playgrounds app? Sometimes they are quite different. Also, are there any other files in the playground, or is it a brand new one?

Comment: I’m curious as to how you’re defining, or intend to define “teacherMode”

Comment: After I read all comments, I see that I can set the teacher value in a variable.    Maybe somebody will need the compiler directives in the future.

Comment: I do need to be able to set the compiler flag as I’m conditionally setting an initializer which can’t be done with a variable as it needs to be set at compile time.  Did anyone find an answer to this?